# Interop, Cannot embed, but embed IS set to false

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, embed

OK, I have an Assembly (let's call it assembly1) that has both a COM API (OurAPI) and a .NET API (Our.API)

I can access the com side in a project with no problems, set the reference, set Embed Interop to False, and away we go.  There are a couple of missing routines in the COM side so I'm trying to use the .NET side

Change the reference (drop the com, point to the DLL, even delete the interop dlls), change the references to OurAPI to Our.API, make sure Embed Interop = false

and I get

Cannot embed interop type  found in both assembly  and . Consider setting the 'Embed Interop Types' property to false.

This is in VS2013, C#5
(note the assembly name is the SAME on both sides)

Comment: Figured it out - it's a bug in the DLL, as it was compiled for 64 bit only, or COM only if 32 bit, and there is a duplicate method (same signature) on the two interfaces, so it is conflicting with itself.  aka NOT a .NET issue, but an issue in the DLL

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - it's a bug in the DLL, as it was compiled for 64 bit only, or COM only if 32 bit, and there is a duplicate method (same signature) on the two interfaces, so it is conflicting with itself.  aka NOT a .NET issue, but an issue in the DLL